# importing invoices in Odoo it throw error always

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

when I try to import an excel of provider invoice it always gives the following error in Odoo 13.

"account_move_line" violates the "check" constraint "account_move_line_check_accountable_required_fields

In a new database import correctly, but I need to import it into a database that already has data

Answer (score 0):

From my short research it looks like you need to have accounting fully set up, as this error occurs when all necessary fields and payment journals are not fully set up. Here's a link to a thread on this from the odoo website: https://www.odoo.com/forum/invoicing-5/what-is-the-template-for-customer-invoces-importing-152187